# SQL How to create where clause to filter last six periods with this format YYYYMM?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run a query with a criteria that sums the previous 6 periods with the following period format `YYYYMM`.

```
SELECT sum(t.usage)
FROM t
WHERE t.peroid ?????
GROUP BY t.period

Period   Usage
-------------
201907   30
201908   40
201909   50
201910   60
201911   70
201912   60
202001   20
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? SQL is just a query language and date/time functions are usually vendor specific

Comment: What is the type of `t.period`? `INT`? `CHAR(6)`? `DATETIME`? From where do you calculate "the previous 6 periods" -- from periods actually in the table, or the current date?

Comment: INT. Start from current period which is 202001

Comment: The database is sql server db

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select  t.period        as  "Period",
        sum(t.usage)    as  "Usage"
from    t
where   t.peroid >= cast(convert(char(6),dateadd(month, -6, cast(convert(char(6),getdate(),112)+'01' as date)),112) as int)
group by t.period
order by t.period
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could achieve this using `OFFSET`:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Usage
    FROM dbo.t
    ORDER BY t.Period DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 6 ROWS ONLY)
SELECT SUM(Usage)
FROM CTE;
```

Comment: Giving error - Column "UsageDetails.Period" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query.

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = getdate()

SELECT sum(TotUsage)
FROM (
    SELECT sum(t.usage) AS Totusage
    FROM UsageDetails t
    GROUP BY t.period
    HAVING t.period BETWEEN Convert(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(month, - 6, @startDate), 112)
            AND Convert(VARCHAR(6), @startDate, 112)
        AND t.period > Convert(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(month, - 6, @startDate), 112)
    ) a
```

Here is the live [**example**](https://rextester.com/IHKG23650).